# Llinker cannot fine function decleared in glext.h with GLVND OpenGL

Tags: linux, opengl

ld parameter contains:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
```

It throw `undefined reference to` glGetUnsignedBytevEXT'`

If I add `-lGL` then the linker is happy. But the libGL.so is not GLVND? How can I link function in libext.h to GLVND library?
`nm -gD` cannot show any glext function in libOpenGL.so, libEGL.so or libGLX.so. Does that means the GLVND library does not contain any glext functions or I still miss some parts? Do I need to somehow load the functions from some proc getter function?

Comment: What is "GLVND"?

Comment: GL Vendor Neutral Dispatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [nice guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/linking-opengl-server-side-rendering/): When use GLVND library, all the functions in glext.h need to use `glXGetProcAddress()` or `eglGetProcAddress()` to load.